# Sensu does not seem to make a connection to a client

Tags: debian, rabbitmq, chef-infra, sensu

I installed Sensu 0.18.1 on Debian 7.8.0 by using chef. Installation seems completed successfully, but for some reason client does not appear on Uchiwa dashboard.

The server log says "unsubscribing from keepalive and result queues" warning. I'm not sure what this message means...

And I found this message that rabbitMQ fails connection. But this seems like that the connection once succeeded, then fails in a minute. It doesn't make sense what this message means.

/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@debianSensuServer.log

```
=INFO REPORT==== 24-Aug-2015::20:01:30 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.9084.0> (127.0.0.1:59174 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Aug-2015::20:01:30 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.9084.0> (127.0.0.1:59174 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{bad_header,<<129,15,1,3,3,0,246,0>>}
```

How do I fix this problem and show the client on Uchiwa dashboard?

I have a poor knowledge about this field, so any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

/var/log/sensu/sensu-server.log

```
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.089922-0400","level":"warn","message":"loading config file","file":"/etc/sensu/config.json"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.090311-0400","level":"warn","message":"loading config files from directory","directory":"/etc/sensu/conf.d"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.109140-0400","level":"warn","message":"loading extension files from directory","directory":"/etc/sensu/extensions"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.109842-0400","level":"warn","message":"loaded extension","type":"mutator","name":"json","description":"returns JSON formatted event data"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.109929-0400","level":"warn","message":"loaded extension","type":"mutator","name":"ruby_hash","description":"returns ruby hash event data"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.109999-0400","level":"warn","message":"loaded extension","type":"mutator","name":"only_check_output","description":"returns check output"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.110067-0400","level":"warn","message":"loaded extension","type":"handler","name":"debug","description":"returns raw event data"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.247597-0400","level":"warn","message":"reconnecting to transport"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:38:15.247803-0400","level":"warn","message":"unsubscribing from keepalive and result queues"}
```

/var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log

```
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:26:57.291895-0400","level":"warn","message":"loading config file","file":"/etc/sensu/config.json"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:26:57.292039-0400","level":"warn","message":"loading config files from directory","directory":"/etc/sensu/conf.d"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:26:57.294905-0400","level":"warn","message":"loading extension files from directory","directory":"/etc/sensu/extensions"}
{"timestamp":"2015-08-24T19:26:57.450583-0400","level":"warn","message":"reconnecting to transport"}
```

Comment: can you output the content of your config file and confirm that Sensu has connection to the Redis Server which I assume is on localhost for your case. Please also put if you have IPv6 enabled.

If you want you can also edit the /etc/default/sensu file and set the log level to debug, then restart the sensu-server using the init script

I recently ran into similar issues and then problem was with the Redis connection, which was quite misleading.